# I am trying to dump all data in txt file, but the things it's dumping only last line

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to dump table rows in txt file using beautiful soup and python but the things is it's only dumping last line of str.

```
html = await page.content()

soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(html,'lxml')

table = soup.find('table', attrs={'class':'a-bordered a-horizontal-stripes mt-table'})
table_rows = table.find_all('tr')

for tr in table_rows:
    td = tr.find_all('td', attrs={'data-column' : 'purchase_order'})
    row = [tr.text for tr in td]
    listToStr = ' '.join([str(elem) for elem in row])
  
    print(type(listToStr)) 

with open('readme.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(listToStr)
```

I'm attaching some of the output screenshot below :

1. [data type of listToStr](https://i.stack.imgur.com/COKDu.png)
2. [data in listToStr](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ixDrq.png)
3. [data dumped into text file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JhDRF.png)

Comment: You are overwriting listToStr in each iteration of the loop. Change it to listToStr += ...

Comment: ```listToStr=""
    for tr in table_rows:
      td = tr.find_all('td', attrs={'data-column' : 'purchase_order'})
      row = [tr.text for tr in td]
      listToStr = ' '.join([str(elem) for elem in row])
      listToStr = listToSTr + '\n'```

correct your loop like this and then 

    with open('readme.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(listToStr)

Comment: `listToStr=""

for tr in table_rows:
    td = tr.find_all('td', attrs={'data-column' : 'purchase_order'})
    row = [tr.text for tr in td]
    listToStr = ' '.join([str(elem) for elem in row])
    listToStr = listToStr + '\n'
    print(listToStr) 
with open('readme.txt', 'w') as f: f.write(listToStr)` I tried implement as you suggested but still the problem is same  @AjayRathore

Comment: Yes I just saw :D `open('readme.txt', 'w')` change this to ` open('readme.txt', 'a')`
'w' overwrites the file everytime you open file with w. So it writes all the lines but also deleted all the previous ones

Comment: Yea, Lol I don't know how I forgot to append the text, anyway Thanks @AjayRathore